# Implementing Windsor, migrating and have questions

Tags: asp.net-mvc, castle-windsor, linkedin-api, ioc-container

I have recently implemented Windsor on a new MVC project(new to both) and am having trouble implementing a service with it.

The service is a [small toolkit project for linkedin that uses c#](https://github.com/deeja/LinkedInDeveloperToolkit). In the sample provided the service can be set up like so:

In App_Start/AuthConfig.cs I create a new instance of `linkedInOAuthClient`, the main object for using the toolkit.

```
LinkedInOAuthClient linkedInOAuthClient = new LinkedInOAuthClient(new CookieAccessTokenStorage(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiSecret"]),
            new DotNetOpenAuthWebConsumer(ServiceDescriptions.Authenticate,
                new InMemoryOAuthTokenManager(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiKey"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["apiSecret"])));
```

I then set a static object `LinkedInService` that implements `ILinkedInService` to `linkedInOAuthClient`

```
LinkedInServiceHelper.LinkedInService = linkedInOAuthClient;
```

Then in my controller

```
public ILinkedInService LinkedInService { get; set; }
public HomeController(ILinkedInService linkedInService)
    {
        LinkedInService = linkedInService;
    }
```

in order to use the service.

**My question is this: How I do migrate LinkedInService to use Windsor?**

I have already registered LinkedInService as a facility and installed it in Windsor

```
public class LinkedInFacility : AbstractFacility
{
    protected override void Init()
    {

        Kernel.Register(Component.For<ILinkedInService>()
                                 .ImplementedBy<LinkedInOAuthClient>().LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

But I am at a loss as to how to implement `linkedInOAuthClient`

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to do anything except registering that created instance in the container:

```cs
Kernel.Register(Component.For<ILinkedInService>()
    .Instance(LinkedInServiceHelper.LinkedInService)));
```